# JQuery: selecting elements by class that are not children specific class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Using JQuery, I would like to select all '.fittext' elements that are not children of '.slick-cloned'.
Here's my code:

```
<div class="slick-slide slick-cloned">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="fittext"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slick-slide active">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="fittext"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slick-slide">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="fittext"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slick-slide slick-cloned">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="fittext"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What should my selector look like?
I tried various combinations but can't seem to do it right... My last trial was:

```
'$(".slick-slide .fittext").not('.slick-slide.slick-cloned')'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By *children* do you mean direct children or descendants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `:not` selector

```
$(".slick-slide:not(.slick-cloned) .fittext")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working perfectly!
I didn't really understand the `:not` selector but your reply made it way clearer.

Comment: I'm happy to signing a help to understand `:not` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('.slick-slike').not('.slick-cloned').find('.fittext');
```

To get a generalized solution you can use `.filter( fn )`:

```
$('.fittext').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('.slick-cloned').length == 0;
});
```

```js
$('.fittext').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('.slick-cloned').length == 0;
})
.text('THIS');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slick-slide slick-cloned">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="fittext">x</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slick-slide active">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="fittext">x</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slick-slide">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="fittext">x</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slick-slide slick-cloned">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="fittext">x</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve by .each(), as below ::

```
$(".slick-slide").each(function(){
   if(!$(this).hasClass("slick-cloned"))
   {
     alert($(this).find("div.fittext").text());
   }    
});
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k2nheho0/1/)